# Multi Threading and Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, awt

I am having a problem in running two threads in parallel. Each of the threads run fine individually. My requirement is to display 10 balls, a red ball if `value` is `0` and a green ball if `value` is `1`, one after the other. The data in `value` is received from an array containing `0`s or `1`s. I need to run 16 such threads together. I am currently trying with two.

```
package pkg2;
public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Intermediate frame = new Intermediate();
    }
}
```

The main class calls the intermediate class

```
package pkg2;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Intermediate extends JFrame {

    public Intermediate() {
        DivScreen ob = new DivScreen();
        ob.setBackground(Color.black);
        ob.divScreen1(16);
        add(ob);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1370, 740);
        setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

In an intermediate class, an object of `DivScreen` class is made where all the threading and GUI part is done.

```
package pkg2;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DivScreen extends Canvas implements Runnable//,ActionListener
{

    Thread t1[];            //threads
    int i, j;               //n=total no. of lines, i=no. of rows, j=no of columns
    public static int x;    // x is now global variable
    public static int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;   //to continue fetching data from last entry
    public static int c1 = 0, c2 = 0;   // to check whether line is working or not
    public static int y1, y2;   // to show red or green balls
    public static int k1 = 0, k2 = 0;   //to draw 10 balls
    int green, blue, red;   //variables for color of lines
    int arr1[] = {1, 1, 0, 1};
    int arr2[] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};

    public DivScreen() //default.  constructor
    {
        //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
        setFont(f);
    }

    public void divScreen1(int m) {
        t1 = new Thread[2]; //HERE WE HAVE TO PAAS n AS SIZE OF THREAD ARRAY 
        // BUT JUST TO CHECK ITS WORKING WE ARE USING 2 THREADS 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            t1[i] = new Thread(this, (i + 1) + "thread");
            t1[i].start();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            j = i;                              //j is for horizontal lines
            g.drawLine(i * 342, 0, i * 342, 740); //i is for vertical lines
            g.drawLine(0, j * 185, 1370, j * 185);
        }
        if (x == 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawString("Line 1", 150, 50);
            if (c1 == 0) {
                g.drawString("Line is not in use", 30, 150);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(45, 90, 200, 30);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(30, 120, 250, 30);
                if (k1 < 10) {
                    if (y1 == 0) {
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                    }
                    g.fillOval(50 + 20 * (k1++), 100, 15, 15);
                } else {
                    k1 = 0;
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(45, 90, 200, 30);
                }
            }
        }

        if (x == 2) {
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.drawString("Line 2", 460, 50);
            if (c2 == 0) {
                g.drawString("Line is not in use", 370, 150);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(385, 90, 200, 30);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(370, 120, 250, 30);
                if (k2 < 10) {
                    if (y2 == 0) {
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                    }
                    g.fillOval(390 + 20 * (k2++), 100, 15, 15);
                } else {
                    k2 = 0;
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(385, 90, 200, 30);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("1thread")) {
                x = 1;
                int value = 0;              // to get value from array              
                while (i1 < 4) {
                    c1 = 1;
                    value = arr1[i1];   //valid is a value containing 1 or 0 
                    i1++;               // 1 implies product is OK, 0 implies product not OK

                    System.out.println(value);
                    if (value == 1) {
                        y1 = 1;         // we will check its value in paint() function
                    } else {
                        y1 = 0;
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            repaint(0, 0, 342, 185);
                        }
                    });


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }

                c1 = 0;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        repaint(0, 0, 342, 185);
                    }
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }

            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("2thread")) {
                x = 2;
                int value2 = 0;                 // to get value from arr2[]

                while (i2 < 6) {
                    c2 = 1;
                    value2 = arr2[i2];
                    i2++;
                    System.out.println(value2);
                    if (value2 == 1) {
                        y2 = 1;
                    } else {
                        y2 = 0;
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            repaint(342, 0, 342, 185);
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                }

                c2 = 0;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        repaint(342, 0, 342, 185);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please reply if you could find something.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks very odd to have a class that is both a JComponent and a Runnable.

Comment: Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JFrame`) & AWT (e.g. `Canvas`) components without good reason.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with multi-threading.

Just an example:

- x is a static variable that is going to be changed by both threads and also used in paint(). You cannot guarantee anything on the state of x at the beginning or during the execution of paint(). The threads might just change it at will.

I suggest that you read a little more on threads and concurrency and how you can manage it but I would say that the biggest problem is the design of the program itself. What exactly are you trying to achieve and why is multithreading needed? If you want to make extensive calculations on what to paint it is ok to have multiple threads for these calculations but the painting method should receive that information in a concurrently safe manner. Only one single thread should do the paint job and the information used during the paint should be locked.